# Excel VBA Userform Context Menu Class Code

Tags: excel, vba, contextmenu, userform

Creating a contextual menu within an Excel User form that applies to Images...

I am trying to write a piece of VBA code to allow me to use a contextual menu generated from right clicking an `Image` on an Excel User form.

Andy Pope kindly gave the world a great bit of code to add a simple context menu that applies to textboxes within an Excel User form, but not `Userform.Image`s.

http://www.andypope.info/vba/uf_contextualmenu.htm

I have edited his code ever so slightly to prevent the contextual usage of `Locked = True` textboxes.

```
'Copyright ©2007-2014 Andy Pope
Option Explicit

Private Const mEDIT_CONTEXTMENU_NAME = "ajpiEditContextMenu"
Private Const mCUT_TAG = "CUT"
Private Const mCOPY_TAG = "COPY"
Private Const mPASTE_TAG = "PASTE"

Private m_cbrContextMenu As CommandBar
Private WithEvents m_txtTBox As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents m_cbtCut As CommandBarButton
Private WithEvents m_cbtCopy As CommandBarButton
Private WithEvents m_cbtPaste As CommandBarButton
Private m_objDataObject As DataObject
Private m_objParent As Object
Private Function m_CreateEditContextMenu() As CommandBar
'
' Build Context menu controls.
'
    Dim cbrTemp As CommandBar
    Const CUT_MENUID = 21
    Const COPY_MENUID = 19
    Const PASTE_MENUID = 22

    Set cbrTemp = Application.CommandBars.Add(mEDIT_CONTEXTMENU_NAME, Position:=msoBarPopup)
    With cbrTemp
        With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "Cu&t"
            .FaceId = CUT_MENUID
            .Tag = mCUT_TAG
        End With
        With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "&Copy"
            .FaceId = COPY_MENUID
            .Tag = mCOPY_TAG
        End With
        With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Caption = "&Paste"
            .FaceId = PASTE_MENUID
            .Tag = mPASTE_TAG
        End With
    End With

    Set m_CreateEditContextMenu = cbrTemp

End Function
Private Sub m_DestroyEditContextMenu()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(mEDIT_CONTEXTMENU_NAME).Delete
    Exit Sub
End Sub
Private Function m_GetEditContextMenu() As CommandBar

    On Error Resume Next

    Set m_GetEditContextMenu = Application.CommandBars(mEDIT_CONTEXTMENU_NAME)
    If m_GetEditContextMenu Is Nothing Then
        Set m_GetEditContextMenu = m_CreateEditContextMenu
    End If

    Exit Function

End Function
Private Function m_ActiveTextbox() As Boolean
'
' Make sure this instance is connected to active control
' May need to drill down through container controls to
' reach ActiveControl object
'
    Dim objCtl As Object

    Set objCtl = m_objParent.ActiveControl
    Do While UCase(TypeName(objCtl)) <> "TEXTBOX"
        If UCase(TypeName(objCtl)) = "MULTIPAGE" Then
            Set objCtl = objCtl.Pages(objCtl.Value).ActiveControl
        Else
            Set objCtl = objCtl.ActiveControl
        End If
    Loop
    m_ActiveTextbox = (StrComp(objCtl.Name, m_txtTBox.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0)

ErrActivetextbox:
    Exit Function

End Function
Public Property Set Parent(RHS As Object)
    Set m_objParent = RHS
End Property
Private Sub m_UseMenu()

    Dim lngIndex As Long

    For lngIndex = 1 To m_cbrContextMenu.Controls.Count
        Select Case m_cbrContextMenu.Controls(lngIndex).Tag
        Case mCUT_TAG
            Set m_cbtCut = m_cbrContextMenu.Controls(lngIndex)
        Case mCOPY_TAG
            Set m_cbtCopy = m_cbrContextMenu.Controls(lngIndex)
        Case mPASTE_TAG
            Set m_cbtPaste = m_cbrContextMenu.Controls(lngIndex)
        End Select
    Next

End Sub
Public Property Set TBox(RHS As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set m_txtTBox = RHS
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set m_objDataObject = New DataObject
    Set m_cbrContextMenu = m_GetEditContextMenu

    If Not m_cbrContextMenu Is Nothing Then
        m_UseMenu
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()

    Set m_objDataObject = Nothing
    m_DestroyEditContextMenu

End Sub
Private Sub m_cbtCopy_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)

    ' check active textbox is this instance of CTextBox_ContextMenu
    If m_ActiveTextbox() Then
        With m_objDataObject
            .Clear
            .SetText m_txtTBox.SelText
            .PutInClipboard
        End With
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub m_cbtCut_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
If m_txtTBox.Locked = True Then
Exit Sub
End If

    ' check active textbox is this instance of CTextBox_ContextMenu
    If m_ActiveTextbox() Then
        With m_objDataObject
            .Clear
            .SetText m_txtTBox.SelText
            .PutInClipboard
            m_txtTBox.SelText = vbNullString
        End With
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub m_cbtPaste_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
If m_txtTBox.Locked = True Then
Exit Sub
End If

    ' check active textbox is this instance of CTextBox_ContextMenu
    On Error GoTo ErrPaste

    If m_ActiveTextbox() Then
        With m_objDataObject
            .GetFromClipboard
            m_txtTBox.SelText = .GetText
        End With
    End If

ErrPaste:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
Private Sub m_txtTBox_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)

    If Button = 2 Then
        ' right click
        m_cbrContextMenu.ShowPopup
    End If

End Sub
```

What can I add to this code for the same context menu to apply with Images?
Something along the lines of...

Adding `Private WithEvents m_imgImage As MSForms.Image`

```
Private m_cbrContextMenu As CommandBar
Private WithEvents m_txtTBox As MSForms.TextBox

Private WithEvents m_imgImage As MSForms.Image

Private WithEvents m_cbtCut As CommandBarButton
Private WithEvents m_cbtCopy As CommandBarButton
Private WithEvents m_cbtPaste As CommandBarButton
Private m_objDataObject As DataObject
Private m_objParent As Object
Private Function m_CreateEditContextMenu() As CommandBar
```

Declaring a `New Private Function`

```
Private Function m_ActiveImage() As Boolean
'
' Make sure this instance is connected to active control
' May need to drill down through container controls to
' reach ActiveControl object
'
    Dim objCtl As Object

    Set objCtl = m_objParent.ActiveControl
    Do While UCase(TypeName(objCtl)) <> "IMAGE"
        If UCase(TypeName(objCtl)) = "MULTIPAGE" Then
            Set objCtl = objCtl.Pages(objCtl.Value).ActiveControl
        Else
            Set objCtl = objCtl.ActiveControl
        End If
    Loop
    m_ActiveImage = (StrComp(objCtl.Name, m_imgImage.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0)

ErrActiveimage:
    Exit Function

End Function
```

I would need to declare a new `Public Property Set`

```
Public Property Set Img(RHS As MSForms.Image)
    Set m_imgImage = RHS
End Property
```

Each context menu option would need altering to include the possibility of a user right clicking on an image...

```
Private Sub m_cbtCopy_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)

    ' check active image is this instance of CTextBox_ContextMenu
    If m_ActiveTextbox() Then
        With m_objDataObject
            .Clear
            .SetText m_txtTBox.SelText
            .PutInClipboard
        End With
    End If

    ' check active image is this instance of CImage_ContextMenu
    If m_ActiveImage() Then
        With m_objDataObject
            .Clear
            'What would be the image alternative for this next line of code?
            '.SetText m_imgImage.SelText
            .PutInClipboard
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

*You will note that I am only using the `Copy` feature of the context menu as `Cut`ting and `Paste`ing from within an User form will not be required (or stable for that matter!).

And finally I would need to recreate the trigger...

```
Private Sub m_imgImage_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As Single, ByVal y As Single)

    If Button = 2 Then
        ' right click
        m_cbrContextMenu.ShowPopup
    End If

End Sub
```

It seems like an awful lot of unnecessary work, there must be an easier way.

Any help or advice is much appreciated, and once again thank you for your time.

Mr J.

Comment: Wow. You really have put much work in the creation of this question. But it is kind of overwhelming... I don't even know where to start reading. Is there any possibility of cutting down the content to the important part of the question? Reading through dozens of lines of code isn't quite attractive.

Comment: @EngJon I like my detail :) I know it's a bit overwhelming, the reason I included all of the code here is so you can see the working context menu for a textbox _(I know a lot of people like to sample 'question code' to get a better understanding)_. The individual code blocks afterwards are my failed attempts at getting it to work with images. The code for working with textboxes is perfect! I just need help making adjustments to make it work with images.

Comment: `'What would be the image alternative for this next line of code?
            '.SetText m_imgImage.SelText`    Possibly `m_imgImage.picture`

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question right, you just want to respond to all image click in one sub. This is how I do it. First create a class called ImageClickResponder (for this example) and add the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Properties
    Obj As Object
    Procedure As String
    CallType As VbCallType
End Type

Private this As Properties

Private WithEvents img As MSForms.Image

Public Sub Initialize(ByRef imgRef As MSForms.Image, ByRef Obj As Object, ByVal procedureName As String, ByVal CallType As VbCallType)
    Set img = imgRef
    With this
        Set .Obj = Obj
        .Procedure = procedureName
        .CallType = CallType
        Debug.Print imgRef.Name
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub img_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    VBA.CallByName this.Obj, this.Procedure, this.CallType, Button, Shift, X, Y
End Sub
```

Then in your user form put this:

```
Option Explicit

Private micrs() As ImageClickResponder

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    micrs = LoadImageClickResponders(Me)
End Sub

Public Sub AllImgs_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Debug.Print "Your context menu code here"
End Sub

Private Function LoadImageClickResponders(ByRef frm As MSForms.UserForm) As ImageClickResponder()
    Dim rtnVal() As ImageClickResponder
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim i As Long

    For Each ctrl In frm.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.Image Then
            ReDim Preserve rtnVal(i) As ImageClickResponder
            Set rtnVal(i) = New ImageClickResponder
            rtnVal(i).Initialize ctrl, Me, "AllImgs_MouseDown", VbMethod
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    LoadImageClickResponders = rtnVal
End Function
```